# MySQL: Group by two columns and sum

Tags: php, mysql

Building an inventory system. I have lots of products and each product has three different variables. So for stock totals I want to group by the two columns (product & size) and sum quantity to get stock total.

| product | Size | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Widget one | 2 | 275 |
| Widget one | 2 | 100 |
| Widget two | 3 | 150 |
| Widget two | 2 | 150 |

What I want for output:

| product | Size | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Widget one | 2 | 375 |
| Widget two | 3 | 150 |
| Widget two | 2 | 150 |

I figured out how to group by one column and sum using the code below:

```
$query = "SELECT product, SUM(Quantity) FROM inventory GROUP BY product";  
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "Total ". $row['product']. " = ". $row['SUM(Quantity)'];
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

I am just stuck on grouping by both columns. Is it possible? or should I just create three different products for the of the three sizes and eliminate that column? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on your example table, it appears you want to be grouping on `product` rather than `id`.  You merely need to add the `Size` column to both the `SELECT` list and the `GROUP BY`

```
$query = "SELECT 
            product,
            Size, 
            SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity 
          FROM inventory
          GROUP BY product, Size";
```

Note that I have added a column alias `TotalQuantity`, which will allow you to more easily retrieve the column from the fetched row via the more sensible `$row['TotalQuantity']`, rather than `$row['SUM(Quantity)']`

Comment: Hey thanks for helping! yeah I changed the table for this question because in real life it's kind of confusing. I fixed the query to match the example table. I am going to try this code right now!

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this. I have only been working with with php and MySQL for about a month now but I am learning so much. This definitely makes sense and I have now added some new knowledge to my coding tool box. Thanks a lot! I will accept as soon as the timer runs out.

Comment: If there was more than one SUMing to be done how would I write the AS function? 
For example SUM(Q1), SUM (Q2), SUM (Q3), etc...

Comment: @AasimAzam `SUM(q1) AS q1, SUM(q2) AS q2, SUM(q3) AS q3, SUM(q4) AS q4)...`