# Mysql get unique count up rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have the following table:

```
| id   | userid | level | amount | workid | time |
| 1    |   1    |   0   |  209   |   1    | 283  |
| 2    |   1    |   1   |  423   |   2    | 283  |
| 3    |   1    |   0   |  4209  |   1    | 283  |
```

How can I get any combination that occured based on the level and work id?

I would like the following returned:

```
level | amount | workid |
   0  |  4418  |  1     |
   1  |  423   |  2     |
```

This means it will count the amount for a specific level and work id and continue giving other combination based on the work id and level.

`Userid` always has variable `$x`, in this case it is `1`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Group by two columns and sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025623/mysql-group-by-two-columns-and-sum)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT level,SUM(amount),workid FROM yourTable
WHERE userid=1
GROUP BY level,workid
```

You can make that `userid=1` a variable according to the code you use

**[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ec62/1)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some simple aggregation. All you need to add the amount is the `SUM()` function, and you can group by level and workid. Then, use a `WHERE` clause to filter out user 1:

```
SELECT level, SUM(amount) AS totalAmount, workid
FROM myTable
WHERE userid = 1
GROUP BY level, workid;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0cfc2/1) example.

Answer (score -1):

Simple,

```
SELECT level,SUM(amount) AS amount,workid FROM table WHERE userId=1
GROUP BY level,workid;
```