# SQL Server : Group by two columns and Sum a third column with the bifurcation of two groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am creating an invoice system where I need to get the sum of `total_amount` with using two filters i.e, `month` and `category_of_service`

So far I am able to use `GROUP BY` clause according with two filters but my `SUM` is calculated as whole, not according to the groups.

I have referred to various questions yet unable to find my solution.

[MySQL: Group by two columns and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025623/mysql-group-by-two-columns-and-sum)

```
month | category_of_service | total_amount
------|---------------------|-------------
12    | EB                  | 1000
12    | EB                  | 1200
12    | DG                  | 1500
12    | DG                  | 2000
```

What I am able to do is

```
month | category_of_service | total_amount
------|---------------------|-------------
12    | EB                  | 5700
12    | DG                  | 5700
```

What I actually want is

```
month | category_of_service | total_amount
------|---------------------|-------------
12    | EB                  | 2200
12    | DG                  | 3500
```

**Note:** There are multiple `months` and `category_of_services`

The query I'm using is:

```
SELECT 
    month, category_of_service, SUM(total_amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM  
    dbo.report
GROUP BY 
    month, category_of_service
```

Here is a screenshot of my output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgvYT.png)

Comment: The query you posted can't return `5700`, it will be the result you want.

Comment: @Shubham Katta The query you posted is the right query unless you have missed writing category_of_service in your query

Comment: Your query is 100% correct

Comment: But the output that I'm getting is not as per the query.@dnoeth

Comment: I have shared the relevant image as well

Comment: maybe you should be filtering the year as well, in the image you are filtering per year...

Comment: for testing purpose, I have disabled that for a while. @rigerta

Comment: Please tell us more about where this data is coming from.  Is `dbo.report` based on a single table or query, or is it based on multiple tables?

Comment: @toonice It is a single table query

Answer (score 0):

```
 ;With Cte([month] , category_of_service , total_amount)
AS
(
SELECT 12    , 'EB', 1000 Union all
SELECT 12    , 'EB', 1200 Union all
SELECT 12    , 'DG', 1500 Union all
SELECT 12    , 'DG', 2000 
)
, Result
AS
(
SELECT * ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION by total_amount ORDER BY [month] desc)  AS Seq FROM
(
SELECT [month] , category_of_service ,Sum(total_amount)OVER(PARTITION BY [month],category_of_service ORDER BY [month])AS total_amount  FROM Cte
)dt
)
SELECT [month] , category_of_service , total_amount FROM Result WHERE seq=1
```

---

OutPut

```
month | category_of_service | total_amount
------|---------------------|-------------
12    | EB                  | 2200
12    | DG                  | 3500
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your Answer, please include an explanation of what was causing the problem for the Questioner, how it was doing so, and *how* your answer fixes the situation.